# JS stopwatch timer with H:m:s:ms format, the minutes won't reset when it reach 60 min

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I make a JS stopwatch that has format H:m:s:ms when it reached 60 min it always increase to 61,62 and so on

i am using setInterval here is my code:

```
n = 3600;
    td = setInterval(function () 
    {
      n++;
      let hours = parseInt(n / 3600);
      var m = parseInt(n / 60)
      var s = parseInt(n / 60 % 60);
      var M = parseInt(n % 60);

      // let hours = Math.floor(((n[ids] / 1000) / 60) / 60) % 24
      // let m = Math.floor((n[ids] / 1000) / 60) % 60
      // let s = Math.floor(n[ids] / 1000) % 60
      // let M = Math.floor(n[ids] % 1000)

      $("#display0").html(toDub(hours) + ":" + toDub(m) + ":" + toDub(s) + ":" + toDub(M))
    }, 1000 / 60);
```

**full source code**: https://jsfiddle.net/greycat/danvL42s/2/

I am sure there is something wrong with my **m**  variable.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic follows that a second is the rounded value for its fraction of 60 milliseconds, and a minute is the rounded value for its fraction of 60 seconds, so on and so forth.

You can refactor the time variables as below:

```
var M = parseInt(n % 60); 
var s = parseInt(n / 60 % 60);
var m = parseInt(n / 60**2 % 60); 
var hours = parseInt(n / 60**3 % 60);
```

Comment: I want to test if the stopwatch reach 1 hour, what's value should assigned to **n** variable ?

Comment: 60 to the power of 3

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toDub(n){
  return n < 10 ? "0" + n : "" + n
}

$(document).on('click', '.start01', function(event) {
    $(this).attr("style", "display:none");
    var ids = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(5));
    $("#stop" + ids).attr("style", "display:block")
    // console.log(n[ids])
    n = 0;
    td = setInterval(function () 
    {
      n++;
      let hours = parseInt(n / 216000);
      var m = parseInt(n / 3600)
      var s = parseInt(n / 60 % 60);
      var M = parseInt(n % 60);

      // let hours = Math.floor(((n[ids] / 1000) / 60) / 60) % 24
      // let m = Math.floor((n[ids] / 1000) / 60) % 60
      // let s = Math.floor(n[ids] / 1000) % 60
      // let M = Math.floor(n[ids] % 1000)

      $("#display0").html(toDub(hours) + ":" + toDub(m) + ":" + toDub(s) + ":" + toDub(M))
    }, 1000 / 60);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card shadow-sm" style="">
    <h2 style="margin:0px auto;">tim 1</h2>
    <div style="margin:0px auto;">
        <h1 id="display0">00:00:00:00</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body" style="margin:0px auto;">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example"><button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-success start01" style="display:block" id="start0"><i class="bi bi-play"></i>
                    start</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning stop01" style="display:none"
                    id="stop0"><i class="bi bi-pause"></i> pause</button>
                    <br><button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-danger reset01" id="reset0"><i class="bi bi-stop-fill"></i> reset</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why the hours var divided by 216000?

Answer (score 0):

```js
n =0;
td = setInterval(function() {
  n++;
  let hours = parseInt(n / 3600000);
  var m = parseInt(n %3600000 / 60000)
  var s = parseInt(n %3600000 %60000/ 1000);
  var M = parseInt(n %3600000 %60000% 1000);      
  $("#display0").html(toDub(hours) + ":" + toDub(m) + ":" + toDub(s) + ":" + toDub(M));
  if(m==60) {
    n=0;
  }
}, 1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: When
n=0 miliseconds
In First iteration value of n will 1 after increasing, To get the hours I divided n by 3600000 because 1 hourse=3600000 miliseconds
,To get minutes I calculated remaining miliseconds after calculating hourse and then divide remaining miliseconds by 60000  because 1 minutes = 60000 miliseconds, Now To get the seconds I calculated remaining miliseconds after finding minutes and divide by 1000  because 1 seconds=1000,and at the end remaining value of n wiil miliseconds.